# Custom attribute not working in razor mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to validate each input with so below is the code in js

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[data-filter]');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

    var input = inputs[i];
    var state = {
        value: input.value,
        start: input.selectionStart,
        end: input.selectionEnd,
        pattern: RegExp('^' + input.dataset.filter + '$')
    };

    input.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
        if (state.pattern.test(input.value)) {
            state.value = input.value;
        } else {
            input.value = state.value;
            input.setSelectionRange(state.start, state.end);
        }
    });

    input.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
        state.start = input.selectionStart;
        state.end = input.selectionEnd;
    });
}
```

It works perfectly with textbox

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Telephone, new {  id="phone", data_filter="\\+?(?:\\d\\s?){0,13}"})
```

Original regex `^\+?(?:\d\s?){11,13}$` escaped backslash as it was giving error

```
$("#phone").on("focus", function (evt) {
    if(this.value.length < 11)
        alert("Invalid");

});
```

It is not working with razor.What is the issue??

Comment: How exactly it is not working? When do you add your event listeners? Is it on $(document).ready ;?

Comment: You said "It works perfectly with textbox", so where does it not work?